# laravel mongodb nested collection relationship

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, collections, eloquent

i am using laravel mongodb collection in that i have some relationship issues
here is my collection of user in which user have multiple addresses and addresses is save in another collection and that ids is save in user collection

```
{
 "_id":ObjectId("52ffc33cd85242f436000001"),
 "contact": "987654321",
 "dob": "01-01-1991",
 "name": "Tom Benzamin",
 "address_ids": [
  ObjectId("52ffc4a5d85242602e000000"),
  ObjectId("52ffc4a5d85242602e000001")
    ]
}
```

for getting user information and his addresses information i have to make 2 query one for user and other for addresses

can it is possible to get user info with addresses in single query by using eloquent relationship.
Sorry i am new in mongodb collection.

Comment: Where you able to find a solution for this ? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to save the document id's of addresses in the user document like that for what you are trying to achieve. Laravel is all about clean code, that ain't clean.

Make the following relationships:

- User > hasMany > Addresses
- Addresses > belongsTo > User

To load a user object in Laravel including all address objects use eager loading (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

You can write eloquent query as followed in PHP:

```
User::where(...some condition...)->with('addresses')->get();
```

Best Regards,

bdschr

Comment: Specifically can try out "whereHas" and "with" QueryRelations from eloquent.